# Relation between overhead and aggregated transmission data rate

Tags: homework, overhead

My homework asks me to calculate the overhead and aggregated transmission data rate of a RS(\$n\$, \$k\$) code at \$M\$ Gb/s. I know that overhead is the additional data added to correct errors, which is \$\frac{n-k}k\$.

But I don't understand "aggregated transmission data rate". The definition I found is "the amount of data that can be forwarded through the system when considering all ports".

How am I supposed to calculate it based on the information given in my homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure that "aggregated" in this context only means "total", i.e. you have \$M\$ Gb/s of *information bit* bitrate, and what you're being asked about is how much data rate your link needs to transport – i.e. the *code bit* bitrate.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sounds like simply calculate M*n/k ?

Comment: that would at least be what I'd do :)